# no device in android studio with flutter

Tags: android

I installed the **Flutter** correctly and added it in the environment variables and also added Dart
I added an **emulator** and ran it before creating a project as a kind of experiment
When I create a project, it does not give me the device
As shown in the picture[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajGLy.png)

Answer (score 0):

To prepare to run and test your Flutter app on an Android device, you’ll need an Android device running Android 4.1 (API level 16) or higher.

Enable Developer options and USB debugging on your device. Detailed instructions are available in the Android documentation.
Using a USB cable, plug your phone into your computer. If prompted on your device, authorize your computer to access your device.
In the terminal, run the flutter devices command to verify that Flutter recognizes your connected Android device.
Start your app by running flutter run.
By default, Flutter uses the version of the Android SDK where your ADB tool is based. If you want Flutter to use a different installation of the Android SDK, you must set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable to that installation directory.